# Tag Synonym: achivements-> achievements

Tags: discussion, status-completed

'Cause some of us suck at speling. It'll also mean manual clean-up gets automated.

Comment: I am always misspelling this.

Answer (score 2):

I just re-tagged the only question in [achivements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achivements) to [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements), so it should get automagically deleted. There's no reason to keep it around as a synonym as it's just a spelling error.

Comment: I expedited the process anyway by merging the now-defunct tag.

Comment: I think common spelling errors should be kept as synonyms. There are some words that some people just can't spell, and achivemaments is one of them.